# Как извлечь тело письма ?

Tags: php, imap

Есть код:

```
mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");

$emailAddress = 'ххх';
$emailPassword = 'ххх';
$emailHost = 'imap.yandex.ru';
$emailPort = 993;

$connectImap = imap_open('{imap.yandex.ru:993/imap/ssl}INBOX', $emailAddress, $emailPassword) or die ("Error:" . imap_last_error());

// проверим ящик на наличие новых писем
$newLeters = imap_search($connectImap, 'NEW');

// если есть новые письма
if($newLeters){
    // перебираем все письма
    foreach($newLeters as $oneLeter){

        // получаем заголовок
        $header = imap_header($connectImap, $oneLeter);

        // достаем ящик отправителя письма
        $mailFrom = $header->sender[0]->mailbox . "@" . $header->sender[0]->host;
        echo "От кого: $mailFrom <br/>";

        // получаем тему письма
        $subject = $header->subject;
        echo "Тема письма: $subject <br/>";

        // получаем содержимое письма
        $textMail = quoted_printable_decode(imap_fetchbody($connectImap, $oneLeter, 1)); 
       // $textMail = imap_fetchbody($connectImap, $oneLeter, 1); 

        echo "Тело письма: $textMail <br/>";
        echo "<hr/>";

        print_r(mb_detect_encoding($textMail));
    }
}else{
    echo "Нет новых писем";
}
// закрываем соединение
imap_close($connectImap);
```

Заголовок, отправитель печатается корректно. Вместо содержимого письма http://prntscr.com/licvhl

Как получить текст письма?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15539902/php-imap-decoding-messages ?

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что тело письма кодируется в base64 , соответственно вам чтобы посмотреть нужно сделать декодирование. В вашем случае в теле письма вот это

```
http://gurevich.agency
```

Comment: Надо бы пояснить, что тело _этого_ письма в base64, а могло быть и в QP, и простым текстом, и вовсе не быть текстовым. По-хорошему если, то надо разбирать Content-Type, разбирать MIME структуру, искать текстовые части (если нужны именно они) и в них смотреть на Content-Transfer-Encoding.

Comment: @Outtruder было бы здорово если бы вы оформили это полновесным ответом. Увы, мои воспоминания про структуру письма уж как лет 8 не освежались, ответил как смог :)

Answer (score 1):

Я использовал в проекте вот такой вариант:

```
$body = imap_fetchbody($this->mbox(), $this->iteratorPos, 1, \FT_PEEK);
$struct = imap_fetchstructure($this->mbox(), $this->iteratorPos);
switch ($struct->encoding) {
    case \ENCBINARY:
        return imap_binary($body);
    case \ENCBASE64:
        return imap_base64($body);
    case \ENCQUOTEDPRINTABLE:
        return imap_qprint($body);
    case \ENC7BIT:
    case \ENC8BIT:
    case \ENCOTHER:
    default:
        return $body;
}
```

Ошибок поведения не замечал.

---

Обратите внимание, что php-imap - [неофициально в статусе deprecated](https://news-web.php.net/php.internals/107950). Базируется на давно неподдерживаемой библиотеке и это доставляет определённые проблемы.